# Opening VS code through anaconda navigator

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

When I open VS Code through Anaconda navigator, it opens python 2.7.16. I would like it to open up version 3.9.7 which is installed on my mac. On opening vscode through launchpad, the vresion shows to be 3.9.7.

I have checked the settings in json and both show the same path.  I tried changing the interpreter through command palette - select interpreter to the version 3.9.7. But in the vscode terminal, it still shows 2.7.16.

How do I get anaconda navigator to open the correct version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of anconda correspond to different versions of Python. When you use Python 3.9.7, anconda also needs a matched version. Here is the download  [page](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.9.7).